# Allow users to download files from outside of webroot

Tags: php, webserver

I've got a folder where I'm storing a bunch of confidential documents and I authenticate the user when they log in, but I only want them to be able to download a specific file.

How can I retrieve the file using apache/php or something else, preferably to give them a download link for the file without moving the folder into the webroot, storing the files in a database or reading in PHP the file and then spitting it back out to them which seems like a waste of CPU time?

Comment: If the file is outside the webroot there will be no simple link. That's the whole concept of webroot. Thus you need to provide the content with some PHP or move the file outside the webroot.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich:  You probably meant `move the file inside the webroot`.

Comment: Is it just me or isn't this off-topic here?

Comment: @JuliePelletier: you are absolutely right, that's what I've meant.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES:  Typical web server installations have a folder above the webroot which is not visible from the Internet, but available to the applications.  PHP's `open_basedir` is usually set accordingly.  Placing sensitive files inside the web root is unsafe no matter how weird it's named.

Comment: Personally I think it's just better to store the files outside your root and let PHP handle it. Unless you have a huge amount of traffic I don't think it will be any problem to serve a few files. Use a secret signature to create download url's so people can't just "guess" which files are stored. Store the signature in a config file outside the root as well. Guess that's pretty secure to store and serve your files to your users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to think about as a framework like method to implement. Your goal: "Prove someone the ability to download a file only meant for them." Quick solution that can be created into some form of framework: "sha checksums of a specific where a file is created based on pre-defined criteria." In practice:

```
sh-3.2# cd /var/www
sh-3.2# mkdir `echo "Clientname" | shasum5.16 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`
sh-3.2# ls
2acdddd6c15cf298f6b4f0f74050524842dbeff9
sh-3.2# cd 2acdddd6c15cf298f6b4f0f74050524842dbeff9/
sh-3.2# mkdir `echo "John Doe" | shasum5.16 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`
sh-3.2# mkdir `echo "Jane Doe" | shasum5.16 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`
sh-3.2# ls
732979cbd4216928eba0a46c51df458687d949b4    77b39a39ca4e50b5c36014dc99aa46237fc4c064
```

In the first line, we go to our webroot directory. Second line, we make a checksum of the company we are holding files for. (Could be any company including our own.) Third line, we go into that directory. Now, we create specific directories for users in that company. We could store information for a specific person without ever having to worry about them guessing another directory. It's simple and effective without having to jump through hoops and hurdles on permissions, groups, etc.

Comment: This is security by obscurity. URLs are not meant to be secret. You're proposing long lived secret URLs. How will you prevent them being bookmarked, logged,displayed in browsers, etc...? What will you do if an URL is exposed? Make the company change its name?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your primary concern is serving files to the correct authorized user. To do this, look into X-Sendfile for Apache or X-Accel-Redirect for Nginx. This will allow files in a certain directory to be accessed only if the application provides the webserver with the correct header on response.

Comment: That is indeed a good (efficient) solution but you should probably give a very straight-forward answer to the question (ie: The files should be outside of web root).